# visual c# can not load form due to error in my code! LoginDB.Designer.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

There is an error where is says `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.LoginDB_Load);`

The error is

> Error CS1061 'LoginDB' does not contain a definition for 'LoginDB_Load' and no accessible extension method 'LoginDB_Load' accepting a first argument of type 'LoginDB' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
namespace wavemaker
{
    partial class LoginDB
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.btn_Submit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.txt_UserName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txt_Password = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btn_Submit
            // 
            this.btn_Submit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 60);
            this.btn_Submit.Name = "btn_Submit";
            this.btn_Submit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 25);
            this.btn_Submit.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btn_Submit.Text = "Login";
            this.btn_Submit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // txt_UserName
            // 
            this.txt_UserName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(67, 8);
            this.txt_UserName.Name = "txt_UserName";
            this.txt_UserName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(194, 20);
            this.txt_UserName.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // txt_Password
            // 
            this.txt_Password.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(67, 34);
            this.txt_Password.Name = "txt_Password";
            this.txt_Password.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(194, 20);
            this.txt_Password.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 11);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.label1.Text = "Username";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 37);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 13);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 4;
            this.label2.Text = "Password";
            // 
            // LoginDB
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(273, 97);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txt_Password);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txt_UserName);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btn_Submit);
            this.Name = "LoginDB";
            this.Text = "LoginDB";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.LoginDB_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btn_Submit;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt_UserName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt_Password;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, there is no `LoginDB_Load` method shown in your code, but this is a partial class, so there could be another file with `partial class LoginDB` in it.

Comment: The error is telling you that you're referencing a method which doesn't exist.  Do you think it should exist?  Where did you define it?  If you don't think it should exist, why are you referencing it?

Comment: That looks like your LoginDB.Designer.cs file. The `LoginDB_Load` event would normally be in the `LoginDB.cs` file, and isn't automatically generated. You can double-click on the form in designer view to create it. Otherwise, you need to create it manually before you can reference it.

Comment: I'm guessing you double-clicked the designer form by accident and created a Load event for it and then removed the newly created event method thinking it would get rid of the event. To fix, add the method back into your code so your designer will load again. Right-Click your form -> Properties -> Events toolbar icon -> find the Load event and clear/delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.LoginDB_Load);
```

Then Double Click the control "LoginDB" to create another one.